# Docker build partially invalidate cache

Tags: docker, dockerfile

There have been a few cases for where I for example, update dependencies from requirements.txt for use with pip, but the link stays the same since I'm manually pulling from a Github link and not using any versioning. Is it possible to invalidate cache halfway through? That way I don't have to build the entire project again, just a partial section.

I've ran touch on the file to no avail, and didn't see anything from a quick search,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify, "partial section" means every command after pip install. You can't restart using cache once it's invalidated.

This is not really possible currently but there is hacky a solution.

Add `ARG CACHE_DATE=2018-11-28` before pip install

then build with `docker build --build-arg CACHE_DATE=$(date) ....`